# Cakephp 3 : How to add a css class with all input field

Tags: cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.6

I am trying to add a css class `"form-control"` with my all input field using `Cakephp Helper`.

I already created a `Helper`

```
class BootstrapFormHelper extends Helper
{

    protected $_defaultConfig = [];

    public function control($fieldName, array $options = []){
        $options['class'] = 'form-control';
        return parent::control($fieldName, $options);
    }

}
```

I also called it in `appView`

```
public function initialize()
{
   $this->loadhelper('BootstrapForm');
}
```

But no any class added in my form input fields. How can I add a css class with my all input fields ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it like

```
class BootstrapFormHelper extends Helper
{
    public $helpers = ['Form'];
    public function control( $name, $options = [] )
    {
        if( !isset( $options['class'] ) ) {
            $options['class'] = 'form-control';
        }
        return $this->Form->control( $name, $options );
    } 
}
```

After call it in `View/appView.php`

You can use it in your view like

```
<?= $this->BootstrapForm->control('username') ?>
```

output :

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username">
```